# Theorem 1.1 is showing as Theorem 1..1

Tags: pdftex

The compiled output of my latex document is showing the theorem numbers with double dots in-between numbers. For example `Theorem 1.1` is getting printed as `Theorem 1..1`.

I could not figure out what is that I'm missing. I am using the following code:

```
 \documentclass{mathSci}
        \usepackage{lipsum}
        \theoremstyle{plain}
        \newtheorem{theoremS}{Theorem}[section]
        \newtheorem{lemmaS}[theoremS]{Lemma}
        \newtheorem{propositionS}[theoremS]{Proposition}
        \newtheorem{remarkS}[theoremS]{Remark} 
        \newtheorem{definitionS}[theoremS]{Definition}
        \newtheorem{corollaryS}[theoremS]{Corollary}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \begin{theoremS}\label{T1}
    A theorem 
    \end{theoremS}

\begin{theoremS}\label{T2}
Another theorem
\end{theoremS}
    
    \end{document}
```

Everything except this numbering problem is fine. Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: Could you please post a *complete* (compilable) code reproducing your problem?

Comment: The most likely problem is having `\thesection` defined as `\arabic{section}.`, with a trailing period. Add `\renewcommand{\thetheoremS}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theoremS}}` after `\newtheorem{theoremS}{Theorem}[section]`. If you provide a full example we can perhaps help better.

Comment: @Bernard, now I have edited it.

Comment: @egreg, then how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you tell us where we can find `mathSci.cls`? It doesn't appear to be on CTAN and I couldn't find it just now when I googled for it.

Comment: @moewe, I don't know. Somebody sent me this template sometime back. I thought this template is standard. I will let you know whenever I get to know

Comment: I couldn't find it anywhere, but the fact that it causes undesirable output with a standard setup like this makes me think it might be a very specialised document class. In that case I'd probably not use it unless specifically requested. A standard class like `article`, `report` or `book` (or a KOMA-Script class or `memoir`) may be the better choice.

Comment: @egreg, thank yoy very much. It works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the yet unknown `mathSci.cls` does a bad redefinition of `\thesection`, something like

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
```

This is bad under many respects, the main one being that any cross reference to a section will end up with the period.

You have two strategies. One is fixing the template; there are much better ways to have the period following the number in section titles without hardwiring it in `\thesection`.

The other strategy is to do

```
\newtheorem{theoremS}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thetheoremS}{\thesection\arabic{theoremS}}
```

so an additional period is not inserted.